# What is 'Draw Something' Built with?

Tags: android, iphone

I googled this and I found very little information. Anyone knows what framework (Flash?) that is used to create "Draw Something"

Is it native?

**For the thumbs down and those who voted to close**

I know that this is not a programming question. However, I think this could be categorized as a software development question.

I am asking this because I am very impressed with the performance and the flow of the App. I almost felt like this app was built using Flash because the original app is a facebook app built with flash. However, I cannot be sure and I am somewhat skeptical with Flash's performance on mobile devices.

IF my questions are not clear enough. I am wondering whether this app is built native or using some kind of frameworks that are already available out there. I am sure you all know that there are open source game dev frameworks for mobile development (cocos2d, libgdx, etc etc).

Comment: On iOS you could look into the Apple sample code "GLPaint."

Comment: Why not ask them? We can't give you a definitive answer.

Comment: Apple doesn't provide support for flash specially on iOS based devices, so forget about Flash.

Comment: But you can still code in AS3 and port that to iPhone. I have done it and it's possible.

Comment: It is built with Marmalade C++ based mobil development framework. Here is their announcement at Marmalade's forum:  http://www.madewithmarmalade.com//devnet/forum/check-out-draw-something-3

Answer (score 5):

It's a commercial game, not open source, so it is expected that you won't find any information on it.

Here's my guess...

It does not have any native UI components and the iOS version and the Android version are almost identical, so I don't think it's created from their respective SDK's. I think it's all done in opengl es layer, which is very low level and supported by both Android and iOS. OpenGL is written in C, and you can interact with its library using C, which is a supported language for both iOS and Android (through NDK).

You can accomplish this easily with something like Marmalade SDK, which is a cross platform game engine that uses C++.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that it's a commercial game but I am curious if they used any kind of game frameworks that are available out there for mobile development. I was guessing that may be it was built using flash because their original game was on facebook and was built with flash. However, I am skeptical with flash's performance on mobile platform like iOS.